# Create select form attribute from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build a select dropdown from the key and values in my json object but I am not able to get the key value pairs together I have been only successful at getting the key names themselves. Below is what I have been able to complete so far.

This is how I would like the select options to look:

```
 <select id="optSelect">
    <option value="key1">value1</option> <!-- should come from name1 -->
    <option value="key1">value2</option> <!-- should come from name2 -->
 </select>
```

Do I need to make another array to hold the value of each key and then reference accordingly when I build my select options or is there another way or method?

```
    var someObject = {
        "Name1": {
            "key1": "value1",
        },
        "Name2": {
            "key1": "value2",
        }
    }


    var objArray = [];

    for(var i in someObject){
        var key = someObject[i];
        for(var x in key1){
            var nextKey = x;
            var nextVal = key1[x];
            someObject.push(nextKey);
        }
    }

    var optionSelect = document.getElementById("optSelect"),
        selectList = document.createElement("select");

    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    optionSelect.appendChild(selectList);

    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = objArray[i]; // need to get key1 in here for each value in someObject
        option.text = objArray[i]; // need to get value 1 or 2 etc in here for each value name in someObject
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
```

Comment: `for(var x in key1)` here `key1` is undefined

Comment: i saw this var key = someObject[i]; change for this var key1 = someObject[i];

Comment: you also push your results to the same array than the source: maybe `someObject.push(nextKey);` should be `objArray.push(nextKey);`, to go further: `objArray[nextKey] = nextVal;`

Comment: Can you show an example of how you'd like the `<select>` and `<option>` elements to look? It's unclear from your code what should be set for the `value` and text content

Comment: What's the point in having identical `<option>` element values?

Comment: They will eventually be changed out I am just using this as example data. Name2 may have ""key1": "value2", ""key2": "value3" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(var x in key1){`, key1 is undefined here, you need to correct that. Then in your objArray you need to save all key value pairs, pushing just the values in it will make using it later difficult. you can push objects in `objArray`, Also why are you creating selectList and then appending it to optionSelect, you can just directly append your options to optionSelect something like this:

```js
 var someObject = {
        "Name1": {
            "key1": "value1",
        },
        "Name2": {
            "key1": "value2",
        }
    }


    var objArray = [];

    for(var i in someObject){
        var key1 = someObject[i];
        for(var x in key1){
            objArray.push({'key' : x, 'val' : key1[x]});
        }
    }

    var optionSelect = document.getElementById("optSelect"),
        selectList = document.createElement("select");

    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    optionSelect.appendChild(selectList);

    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        
        option.value = objArray[i].key; // need to get key1 in here for each value in someObject
        option.text = objArray[i].val; // need to get value 1 or 2 etc in here for each value name in someObject
        optionSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
```

```html
<select id="optSelect">

 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the original object values, then the keys of each value

```
Object.values(someObject).forEach(entry => {
  Object.keys(entry).forEach(key => {
    let option = document.createElement('option')
    option.value = key
    option.text = entry[key]
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  })
})
```

Reference:

- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

Just a more elegant, maybe, way to put it :)

```js
var values = Object.values,
  keys = Object.keys,
  s = document.createElement('select'),
  someObject = {
    "Name1": {
      "key1": "value1",
    },
    "Name2": {
      "key1": "value2",
    }
  };

values(someObject).forEach((o) => {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.setAttribute('value', keys(o)[0]);
  opt.innerHTML = values(o)[0];
  s.appendChild(opt);
});

document.body.appendChild(s);
```